# Enumerator / Iteratee application never finishes

Tags: scala, playframework, enumerator, loops

When I try the following *'Hello World'* example from [here](http://mandubian.com/2012/08/27/understanding-play2-iteratees-for-normal-humans/), the application will never stop. Is it the Iteratee, waiting for ever more input? I tried to so something like

```
val enumerator = Enumerator(1, 234, 455, 987).andThen(Enumerator.enumInput(Input.EOF))
```

but it does not help.

**What do I have to do to make the application stop after the Iteratee is done with all elements from Enumerator?**

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Experiment 
{       
  def main(args: Array[String]) 
  {
     val enumerator = Enumerator(1, 234, 455, 987)
     enumerator(Iteratee.foreach( println _ ))

     // same result with apply   
     //enumerator.apply(Iteratee.foreach( println _ ))

     println("Main is done pretty soon but the application will never stop.")
   }
}
```

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but I just ran your example (with Play 2.4.6) and it stops normally after printing out all 5 lines.